# Upload image to server and store image path in mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, image

I followed this [tutorial](http://geekonjava.blogspot.in/2014/03/upload-image-on-server-in-android-using.html) to upload a image to the server.

**Now my question is how can I modifiy the code to save the image path additionally into a MySql database, after the upload is completed?** Please help on this.

For completition I am showing my current code to upload the image to the server:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private TextView messageText;
    private Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    private String upLoadServerUri = null;
    private String imagepath = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        btnselectpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
        messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);

        btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        upLoadServerUri = "http://10.0.2.2/uploads/UploadToServer.php";
        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (arg0 == btnselectpic) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        } else if (arg0 == uploadButton) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                    "Uploading file...", true);
            messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    uploadFile(imagepath);

                }
            }).start();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath();

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" + imagepath);

        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            dialog.dismiss();

            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + imagepath);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Source File not exist :" + imagepath);
                }
            });

            return 0;

        } else {
            try {

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                    + " F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                ex.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText
                                .setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                        "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block
    }

}
```

The PHP file to store the image on server:

```
<?php  
    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `uploads` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

PHP:

```
$file_path = "uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
  // replace $host,$username,$password,$dbname with real info
  $link=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
  mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `files` (filename,path) VALUES ('".$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']."','".$file_path."')") or trigger_error($link->error."[ $sql]");
  mysqli_close($link);

} else{
    echo "fail";
```

Comment: I adjusted the necessary database information like host, username etc. but it does not insert the path into the table, but the upload to the server still works. Any idea?

Comment: @Sini I have updated the code. try again and check your error log if it does not work.

Comment: ok now it works but one question remains. How can I check if there is already an image path saved, so to avoid duplicates in database? Thanks!

Comment: You could either do an SELECT statement to check if it exists or you can add a unique index to the path and then go for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.jojo.traveldiary;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
public class Add_Trip_Details extends AppCompatActivity 
    {
      EditText title;
      EditText date;
      EditText time;
EditText discription;
TextView heading;
ImageView browseimg;
ImageView captureimg;
ImageView image;
Spinner l;
String imgphoto=null;
String placenameid;
String tripplace;
String tripdate;
ProgressBar progress;
private  Toolbar toolbar;
TextInputLayout titleerror;
TextInputLayout descriptionerror;
int a=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__trip__details);
    placenameid=getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
    tripplace=getIntent().getStringExtra("pey");
    tripdate=getIntent().getStringExtra("dey");
    String currentdate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    heading= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading);
    heading.setText("Add  Details To Your "+tripplace+" Trip");
    titleerror= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);
    descriptionerror= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.view1);
    title= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);
    date= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText13);
    time= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText14);
    discription= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText15);
    browseimg= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    captureimg= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    progress= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar4);
    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    date.setText(currentdate);
    time.setText(strDate);
    l=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String a[]={"Private","Public"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,a);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);
    toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.include);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


}

public  void browseImg(View view)
{
   Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
   startActivityForResult(in, 1);
   // Intent intent = new Intent();
    //intent.setType("image/*");
    //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
}
public  void  captureImg(View view)
{
    Intent in=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(in, 2);
}
public  void submit()
{

   String status= l.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String titlestring=title.getText().toString();
    String descriptionstring=discription.getText().toString();
    String datestring=date.getText().toString();
    String timestring=time.getText().toString();

    //Add_Trip_Details_AsyncTask asynctask=new Add_Trip_Details_AsyncTask(this,status,titlestring,descriptionstring,placenameid);
    //asynctask.execute("");
    if(titlestring.equals(""))
    {
        titleerror.setErrorEnabled(true);
        titleerror.setError("Enter a titile ");
        a=1;

    }
    else
    {
        titleerror.setErrorEnabled(false);
        a=0;
    }
   if(descriptionstring.equals(""))
    {
        descriptionerror.setErrorEnabled(true);
        descriptionerror.setError("Enter Discription ");
        a=1;
    }
   else
   {
       titleerror.setErrorEnabled(false);
       a=0;
   }
   /* if(imgphoto.equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "insert an image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        a=1;
    }
    else
    {

        a=0;
    }*/

    if(a==0)
    {
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params=new RequestParams();
    params.put("title",titlestring);
    params.put("discription", descriptionstring);
    params.put("status", status);
    params.put("p_id", placenameid);
        params.put("trip_date", datestring);
        params.put("cre_time", timestring);
    try {
        params.put("im_name", new File(imgphoto));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  //  Log.e("img path ", imgphoto.toString());
  client.post(AppConstant.WEB_URL+"trip_details.php", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);

            try {

                String status = response.getString("status");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                finish();
                Intent in = new Intent(Add_Trip_Details.this, View_Trip_Details.class);
                in.putExtra("iey", placenameid);
                in.putExtra("pey", tripplace);
                in.putExtra("dey", tripdate);
                startActivity(in);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "faild", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            super.onFinish();
        }
    });
        /*client.post("http://192.168.1.11/Travel_Dairy/trip_details.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {


            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sucess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                finish();
                Intent in = new Intent(Add_Trip_Details.this, View_Trip_Details.class);
                in.putExtra("iey", placenameid);
                in.putExtra("pey", tripplace);
                in.putExtra("dey", tripdate);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
                // Intent in = new Intent(ViewOREdit.this, Home.class);
                // startActivity(in);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "faild", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });*/
   //finish();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Calendar calender=Calendar.getInstance();
    Long lo=calender.getTimeInMillis();

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==2)
    {
      try
      {
          Bitmap bt=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
          image.setImageBitmap(bt);
          savePhoto(bt,lo+".jpg");
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
    else if(requestCode==1)
    {
try
 {
  Uri uri=data.getData();
  String[] path={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
  Cursor cur=getContentResolver().query(uri, path, null, null, null);
  cur.moveToFirst();
  int a=cur.getColumnIndex(path[0]);
  String c=cur.getString(a);
  cur.close();
  image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(c));
  savePhoto(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(c),lo+".jpg");
}
catch(Exception e)
 {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }



    }
}
public void savePhoto(Bitmap imagetosave,String filename) {
    File direct=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"MyTravelDiary");
    if(!direct.exists())
    {
        File newdirectory=new File("/sdcard/MyTravelDiary");
        newdirectory.mkdirs();

    }
    File file=new File(new File("/sdcard/MyTravelDiary"),filename);
    if(file.exists())
    {
        file.delete();
    }
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fo=new FileOutputStream(file);
        imagetosave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fo);
        fo.flush();
        fo.close();
        imgphoto="/sdcard/MyTravelDiary/"+filename;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add__trip__details, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.submit) {
        submit();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.